# ElasticSearch Match_Phrase Query not full text match

Tags: elasticsearch, match-phrase

I used match_phrase query for search full text matching.

But it did not work as I thought.

Does match_phrase query not work with text type?

My query:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
      "query": {
        "match_phrase" : {
            "message" : "Login"
        }
    }
}
```

Search Result:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "my_index",
    "_source": {
      "message": "Login success"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "my_index",
    "_source": {
      "message": "Login operator1"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "my_index",
    "_source": {
      "message": "Login failed"
    }
  }
]
```

My mapping:

```
"message": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
}
```

Help.

Comment: What results did you expect to get?

Comment: Exactly my question too :)

Comment: I expected exactly 'Login' !

Comment: If you want to return only results where message has exactly ‘Login’ and nothing else then search on message.keyword. match_phrase query analyzes the text and creates a phase query out of the analyzed text. If you use a keyword field then it is not analyzed.

Comment: I see. Thanks !